# How to manipulate C++ Vector array into PHP code?

Tags: php, c++, arrays, vector

I have developed one utility in C++ which has some class and return vector array. I need to manipulate C++ Vector array in Php by calling C++ function.

C++ code:

```
class SampleCode
{
  vector <string> vecarray;
  public:
  void setdata()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
          vecarray.push_Back("This is line number "+ (i+1));
     }
  }

  vector <string> getdata()
  {
     return vecarray;
  }
};
```

Php Code:

// Need to get here C++ array and need to format the result in table.

How can this be implemented in Php?

Comment: How about you write a PHP extension that binds PHP with your C++ utility...

Comment: Can u pls post here any example or link to the example doing the same. As i m new to PHp to  bit difficult for me to do it.

Comment: I've never written a PHP extension in C++ before, but I think I'm right in saying that [php-cpp](http://www.php-cpp.com/) is capable enough, and fairly easy (from what I've seen in the docs). All you really need to know is how a `zval` stores a string (get the `char *` using the `Z_STRVAL` macro, then convert it to a `std::string`, and push it onto the vector. The same thing can be done to create a zval from a vector: create a hash table (== `array()`), and convert each `std::string` to a `zval`

Comment: I found PHP-CPP only caste PHP array into C++ array but not vice versa. So pls help me in type casting other way round.

Comment: Converting a `std::string` to a `char *` is the same as in normal C++, to get a `zval` string from a `char *`, there are macro's. It's all in the hacker's guide to the zend engine, [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swig](http://www.swig.org) to manipulate your objects/functions in C++ from PHP.
I never tried with PHP as exit language, but it's in the list.